# ksh script to perform an upgrade

Tags: ksh

Could you please review my script?

```
#!/bin/ksh
T=/bb/bdap/bin/cms/tools
U=$T/upgrader
mv $T/conbase_updates $U/conbase_updates.br.drqs$1
cd $U
grep "^BR" config.alpha > config.br
./ConbaseUpgrader config.br conbase_updates.br.drqs$1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to validate the value of `$1`, or at least that it's not empty, for example add a line like this near the top:

```
test "$1" || { echo usage: $0 param; exit 1; }
```

---

You are not checking for errors, for example what will happen if the `mv` command fails for whatever reason? Maybe you have no reason to suspect a problem there, but just in case it would be good to add the `-e` flag to the shebang (`#!/bin/ksh`) so that execution will stop immediately there. Otherwise execution would continue after the failed `mv`, and the `grep ... > ...` might clobber a file by accident.

In any case, adding the `-e` flag in the shebang is a good practice in general.

---

It seems your variables will not normally contain spaces. If they ever do, remember to quote them properly, for example:

```
mv "$T/conbase_updates" "$U/conbase_updates.br.drqs$1"
```

(in your current example it's unnecessary)